# Managing servers in remote machines

Tags: automation, cross-platform, software-testing

I'm looking for some software which can start & stop processes on remote machines (to be specific, servers we are testing).

Ideally, you could set it up on various machines of different operating systems & versions, upload a binary to some shared location, and tell it to start the process on a, for example, windows 7 machine, and it would pick the machine for you (perhaps doing load balancing of some sort) and tell you which one it was. Even better if it had the capability to keep track of other stuff, such as which ports were in use on each of the machines)

Ideally, it would be able to save the output of the processes, the log files they generate, etc, able to detect when they crash & get a core dump.

Right now we have an in - house solution for this (running on top of bamboo, see [What's the best way of testing client/server programs using Bamboo?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/304039/35861)), but it's a mess and very unreliable, and I was hoping it's a solved problem, for automated client/server testing.

Comment: Here's some context: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/304039/35861

Answer (score 1):

You can do this sort of thing with [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) which in addition to building your software, (possibly in differing build environments or with differing settings), can also run tests and record the results for you as you can see in the posts starting [here](http://bhfsteve.blogspot.com/2012/04/automated-python-unit-testing-code.html).  You can run a master which coordinates all of the instances and it has some load balancing rules available to share the workload between various test machines.

- Cross platform - both master and slaves
- Load balancing
- Great reporting
- Free

Note that most CI tools can be persuaded, with a little effort, to do something similar - since it seems that you are already running Bamboo as your C.I. client you should consult the Bamboo documentation on how to run tests and gather results under Bamboo.

Comment: we already use Bamboo for CI; what about Jenkins would make it more suited for this? (Although I doubt I could get us to change at this point anyway, unless we had them coexist, I guess).

Comment: @Bwmat - Your question only mentioned "some in-house" solution not Bamboo - AFAIK Bamboo should be able to do the same but I know Jenkins better. They should be able to co-exist but the main point to take home _or to work_ is that most CI tools can run tests as well as do builds.

Comment: @Bwmat Please edit your question saying you're already using Bamboo as CI tool. Thank you.